# Apple.com product animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.apple.com/mac/ (the products animating into position)

Anyone know how apple does this?

I don't need useable code. Just an idea of how to accomplish it.

I use the jQuery framework.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Jordan for pointing this out. Apple is using css3 animations for this, not javascript.

If anyone has a good idea on doing this with JS please post.

Comment: Why would someone vote my question down? It doesn't make sense. Comment and explain why you did this.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I'm going to guess *research effort* given that you can simply dig through their JS to find out (As Jordan notes in his answer below).

Comment: I didn't even bother digging under the assumption that they get enough traffic they would minify their JS. Is that wrong to assume?

Comment: You know what they say about assumptions :)

Comment: Thanks Brain for explaining. I can see how someone would think that. Not trying to argue with you by any means.

Comment: They do minify though, just checked. Also it's not even a js animation, it's css3 as Jordan pointed out. I would really like a way to accomplish this in JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple is using CSS3 animations for this. Check out the [CSS file](http://images.apple.com/global/styles/productbrowser.css) and scroll down to `/* animations`.

Comment: Are these webkit specific animations? or css3?

Comment: They are CSS3 and supported in current versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera. I'm not sure about IE10. However the spec is still in flux so you'll notice in the source e.g. different keyframe rules: `-webkit-keyframes`, `-moz-keyframes`, etc., and for the near future you'll have to do the same for the browsers you want to support.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again. I'm ok with it supporting css3. I do not care about people who use old browsers, in the respect to how I am using this.

Answer (score 3):

Here I made a version in jQuery, which works in all browsers. Using this technique, you have many ways to do it using different CSS approaches, like absolute divs inside a relative one, etc. and then changing that values with the jQuery's animate function. I made it as simple as possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/sanbor/SggMG/

HTML

```
<div class="box">one</div>
<div class="box">two</div>
<div class="box">three</div>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<a id="resetAnimation" href="#">Run animation again</a>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100%;
}
.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
}
```

JS

```
function animateBoxes() {
    $('.box').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).animate({
            'marginLeft': '10px'
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            specialEasing: {
                marginLeft: 'easeOutBounce'
            }
        }, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
}

$('#resetAnimation').click(function() {
    $('.box').css('marginLeft', '100%');
    animateBoxes();
});

animateBoxes();
```

Alternate way, with css3 (http://jsfiddle.net/sanbor/SggMG/6/)
This also can be done with css3 transitions, which is more, because just add an smooth effect between property changes, but animation allows to apply certain
HTML

```
<div class="box">one</div>
<div class="box">two</div>
<div class="box">three</div>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<a id="resetAnimation" href="#">Click twice</a>
```

CSS

```
.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
}

.box {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.box.moveit{
    -webkit-animation-name: moveit;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-name: moveit;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -ms-animation-name: moveit;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: moveit;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveit {
  from {
        margin-left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveit {
  from {
        margin-left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveit {
  from {
        margin-left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes moveit {
  from {
        margin-left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

JS

```
$('#resetAnimation').click(function() {
    $('.box').toggleClass('moveit');
});
```

Comment: +1 for cross-browser. But could you add the code to the post? The jsfiddle link is useful, but it's good practice to leave the code in the post. Thanks!