# Apple product list jquery animation how to do it

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

On Apple website there is a very [beautiful product animation](http://www.apple.com/ipod/).

There are a pager on click they get a list of products

Anyone have an idea of how to this or is there a plugin to make something like this?

Comment: My first thought would be to look into JQuery's animate features. Quick starter guide [(here)](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked several times, the following should answer the question.

[Apple.com product animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574016/apple-com-product-animation)